# How do I rename all the files within a directory?

Tags: r, rename

My bamFiles are currently "11.bam"  "114.bam" "132.bam" "60.bam". I want to add chr16_ to the front of each file. These names should be back into the bamFiles character vector.

Code:

```
bamPath = "C:/Users/User/Downloads/chr16_bam"
for(f in bamPath){file.rename(list.files(pattern=".bam$", all.files=F, full.names=F), paste("chr16", sep="_", f))}
```

Traceback:

```
Error in file.rename(list.files(pattern = ".bam$", all.files = F, full.names = F),  : 
  'from' and 'to' are of different lengths
```

Expected output:

```
"chr16_11.bam"  "chr16_114.bam" "chr16_132.bam" "chr16_60.bam"
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am not getting something here. If your issue is just to rename a bunch of files, this should do the trick.

I added to my home folder exactly the files you mentioned: `11.bam`, `114.bam`, `132.bam`, `60.bam`.

```r
> oldfiles = list.files("~/", pattern = "*.bam")
> oldfiles
# [1] "11.bam"  "114.bam" "32.bam"  "60.bam" 
> 
> newfiles = paste0("chr16_", oldfiles)
> newfiles
# [1] "chr16_11.bam"  "chr16_114.bam" "chr16_32.bam"  "chr16_60.bam" 
> 
> file.rename(oldfiles, newfiles)
# [1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
> 
> list.files("~/", pattern = "*.bam")
# [1] "chr16_11.bam"  "chr16_114.bam" "chr16_32.bam"  "chr16_60.bam"
```

Comment: It throws a warning that the files don't exist. 
`Warning messages:
1: In file.rename(old.filename, bamFiles) :
  cannot rename file '11.bam' to 'chr16_11.bam', reason 'The system cannot find the file specified'
2: In file.rename(old.filename, bamFiles) :
  cannot rename file '114.bam' to 'chr16_114.bam', reason 'The system cannot find the file specified'
3: In file.rename(old.filename, bamFiles) :
  cannot rename file '132.bam' to 'chr16_132.bam', reason 'The system cannot find the file specified'
...`

Comment: That's probably due to the specification of the initial path. `~/` refers to the home folder in macOS and/or a Linux system. If you are on Windows, I suppose you need to specify another folder.

Answer (score 0):

Try This Solution, It's working perfectly at my end, now its your turn

```
> library(reproducible) 
> bamPath = "C:/Users/User/Downloads/chr16_bam"
> files <- list.files(bampath ,pattern = "*.bam",full.names = T)
> sapply(files,FUN=function(eachPath){ 
  file.rename(from=eachPath,to= .prefix(eachPath, "chr16_"))
})
```

Console Logs Should be like this

```
C:/Documents/Sample/16_161.bam                                                                                                              
TRUE 

C:/Documents/Sample/16_162.bam                                                                                                              
TRUE

C:/Documents/Sample/16_163.bam                                                                                                              
TRUE
```

If you're getting `"TRUE"`then its renamed successfully also check
folder where your files kept